# Solving an inequality with logarithms of different bases?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, logarithms

The question is to solve $\log_2x>\log_3x$ for x.

I attempted to simplify it like so:
\begin{align*}
\log_2x&>\log_3x\\
\frac{\log_2x}{\log_22}&>\frac{\log_2x}{\log_23}\\
\log_2x&>\log_2x^{\frac{1}{\log_23}}\\
x&>x^{\frac{1}{\log_23}}
\end{align*}

It feels like I'm really close but not sure how to finish this problem.

Comment: Might be easier to make use of the identity $\log_ab\log_bc=\log_ac$. Also, I don't believe your 3rd inequality.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Ah yes, I meant 1/log2(3). Fixed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the steps below:

$$\log_2x >\log_3x$$
$$\frac{\ln x}{\ln2}>\frac{\ln x}{\ln 3}$$
$$\ln x \left(\frac{1}{\ln2} - \frac{1}{\ln3} \right)>0$$

Since

$$\frac{1}{\ln2} - \frac{1}{\ln3} >0$$

the following must hold,

$$\ln x > 0$$

Thus,

$$x>1$$

Comment: Of course, I feel silly for not thinking of factoring out lnx. I had that earlier and just stared at it wondering how I could go about not cancelling out all my x's. Thanks, marked.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses the same technique you began to use.

Try dividing both sides by $x$. We can do this since taking the logarithm assumes anyway $x\not=0$. You will get:

$$1>x^{\log_3(2) -1}$$

Now find out if $\log_3(2) -1$ is positive or negative and you should be able to finish from there!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I did actually mean log3(2)

Comment: Understood, I figured! I just noticed you were on the right track for a solution, and didn't have to totally change how you got it